# CSS Looping layout columns

Tags: html, css

I have a list like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  .... etc ....
</ul>
```

Instead of it ending up like

```
A
B
C
D
E
...
```

I'd like for it to end up in columns like this:

```
A      B      C
D      E      F
G      H      I
....  etc  (ordered alphabetically)
```

If I had to do this in a server side language, I'd do something like create three arrays, one for each column, and loop through each item, placing it in the correct column, but is there an easier way to do it with CSS3?

Many thanks!

Comment: I've answered this exact question in the past. Use the search function on this site.

Comment: @Mr A , did you find it useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
li {
    display: inline
}

li:nth-child(3n):after {
    content: '\a';
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3UN4f/1/

First i make the list items inline, then the `\a` inserts a line break. Here is the specification for that: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#strings. `nth-child` is CSS3: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Comment: What kind of browser support (do you know?) does this have?

Comment: PS, this is basically the type of solution that I was after.  It looks like there are a lot of other good answers below as well.  Wish I could say everybody's correct!  (Thank you for the answer)

Answer (score 2):

I have two way for you:

1. Use `<table>` in order to have columns
2. Set this CSS for your elements:

```
li {
   width: 100px;
   float: left;
}

ul {
   width: 320px;
}
```

Comment: The code block formatting was colliding with the list formatting. I replaced the 4-space formatting with literal `<pre><code>` HTML tags, and that fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks. I didn't go for debug via other tabs.

Comment: No problem, just thought I'd shed some light on the formatting issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont if this might be appropriate but have a look at the [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3UN4f/)

Comment: Well, I guess I *did* ask for CSS3, so I'm going to accept the first guy's answer.  But I think, for the sake of compatibility, I'm probably going to go with this answer (with the one small change of making the width "33%" instead of pixels).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have different options:

1. Multicolumn-Layout (atm the support in the browsers is not very good) - [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/)
2. put `float:left` and `width:100%/<no of cols>` (for 3 columns = 33%) on the `li`-elements
3. Put a break after `:nth-child(<no of cols>)` via `content` on the pseudo-element.
4. If you have tabular data: use a table